# generate fo:table running title/header by table fragment position

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I found many answers how to generate running titles and table-headers, but no one fits conditions:

1. First table fragment should have title "Title of table $tablenum"
2. From second to rowsCount-1 should have title "Continue of table"
3. Last table fragment should have title "End of table".

I found `retrieve-table-marker`, and put markers on each row, but with it i can fit only in 2 conditions:

- 1-2 (and last table fragment also have "Continue of table" header) with

  ```
  <retrieve-table-marker retrieve-position-within-table="first-starting"/>
  ```
- 2-3 (First fragment have "Continue of table") with

  ```
  <retrieve-table-marker retrieve-position-within-table="last-ending"/>
  ```

So, it can be solved, if i found how to do one of next thing:

1. can determine when xslt processing, that current table fragment is last/first

If it possible, i can set something like

```
<fo:table-row>
  <xsl:choose>  
    <xsl:when test="is-last-fragment()">
      <fo:marker marker-class-name="table-header">End of table</fo:marker>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
      <fo:marker marker-class-name="table-header">End of table</fo:marker>
    </xsl:when>          
    <xsl:otherwise>            
      <fo:marker marker-class-name="table-header">Continue of table</fo:marker>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</fo:table-row>
```

and use `<retrieve-table-marker retrieve-position-within-table="first-starting"/>` in table header.

2. can hide first/last marker with other on `retrieve-table-marker` tag.

I use saxonb-xslt-9.1.0.8J from Saxonica as xslt processor and generate pdf with fop-2.1.

**UPD:**
XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<numbers>
  <number>1</number>
  <number>2</number>
  <number>2</number>
  <number>2</number>
  <number>2</number>
  <number>2</number>
  <number>2</number>
  <number>2</number>
  <number>11</number>
  <number>2</number>
  <!-- and so on. Just dummy lines -->
</numbers>
```

XSL styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.1">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="numbers">
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4">
          <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin="2cm"/>
          <fo:region-before margin="4cm" extent="2cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
        <fo:flow flow-name="body">
          <fo:table>
            <fo:table-column/>
            <fo:table-header>
              <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-color="black">
                  <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="cont"
                    retrieve-position-within-table="last-ending"
                    retrieve-boundary-within-table="table-fragment"/>&#160;
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-header>
            <fo:table-body>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:table-body>
          </fo:table>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="number">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
          <fo:inline>
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1 and position() != last()">continued</xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">ended</xsl:if>
          </fo:inline>
        </fo:marker>
        <fo:block>
          value: <xsl:apply-templates/> on line <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produce XSL-FO:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4">
      <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin="2cm"/>
      <fo:region-before margin="4cm" extent="2cm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
    <fo:flow flow-name="body">
      <fo:table>
        <fo:table-column/>
        <fo:table-header>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-color="black">
                <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="cont" retrieve-position-within-table="last-ending" retrieve-boundary-within-table="table-fragment"/> 
              </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-header>
        <fo:table-body>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
                <fo:inline/>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:block>
                value: 1 on line 1</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
                <fo:inline>continued</fo:inline>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:block>
                value: 2 on line 2</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
                <fo:inline>continued</fo:inline>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:block>
                value: 2 on line 3</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
                <fo:inline>continued</fo:inline>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:block>
                value: 2 on line 4</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
                <fo:inline>continued</fo:inline>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:block>
                value: 2 on line 5</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
                <fo:inline>continued</fo:inline>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:block>
                value: 2 on line 6</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
                <fo:inline>continued</fo:inline>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:block>
                value: 2 on line 7</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
                <fo:inline>continued</fo:inline>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:block>
                value: 2 on line 8</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
                <fo:inline>continued</fo:inline>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:block>
                value: 11 on line 9</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
                <fo:inline>continued</fo:inline>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:block>
                value: 2 on line 10</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
                <fo:inline>continued</fo:inline>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:block>
                value: 11 on line 11</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <!-- and so on... -->
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="cont">
                <fo:inline>ended</fo:inline>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:block>
                value: 12 on line 172</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
      </fo:table>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: You will need to show more parts of the XSLT to allow us to see and understand which nodes are processed. If you have e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>`, then e.g. `<xsl:template match="item"><fo:table-row><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="position() = last()">` might to what you want. Currently we can't tell what you are processing.

Comment: Thanks for help. I add example files, and yes, i use `position() = last()` in generating marker, and it's do the the work - it's generate last marker with "End of table" text(in my example another text, but i thing it's no matter). For catch this this marker, i should use attribute `retrieve-position-marker="last-ending"`, but in this case, on first page it's retrieve last marker with "continue" text, not blank. This is key.